# nested loops of unknown number of loops

Tags: python, algorithm, loops, for-loop

i have problem in which i have to test every element of an array with every other element in of the next array, and every element of the next array with every element of the next next array etc....
naturally i thought about nested loops
but the problem is the number of arrays is given by the user so it would look like this :

```
for i in k:
  for j in a[i]:
      for k in a[i+1]:
        for t in a[i+2]:
            etc.......
```

so its a loop of loops how can i reduce this code???

Comment: If you give more information about what these arrays are/what needs to be done with them it is possible you do not need to structure the code like this

Comment: Could you provide some sample input? It would help to make it more clear what you're looking for.

Comment: In particular, what is `k` here?

Comment: in general if i want to find a certain combination in a N number of arrays , and each length of every array is also given by the user , i found this problem while trying to solve this : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximize-it/problem

Comment: Why not select the maximum value from each list, add the squares of them and return ? You don't need all these loops IMO.

Comment: yes i've seen the correct answer the point is not this, what if the only way to solve this problem is via this method , is there any way to reduce those loops or automate them ?

Answer (score 2):

Recursion can be a good approach for this kind of problems:

```
def nested(a, i, end, elems = []):
    if (i<end):
        for j in a[i]:
            elems.append(j)
            nested(a, i+1, end, elems)
            elems.pop(j)
    else:
        pass # here you can do the operation on the elements

for i in k:
    nested(a, 0, len(a))
```